# Cannot import simplejson outside of /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Tags: python, ubuntu, odoo, simplejson

I am trying to run an Odoo server, but I get a "no module named simplejson" error. I know I've installed it, and I tried again with pip and apt-get to make sure, but they say it's already installed. When I run python and try to `import simplejson` I get the same error **except** when I run it from inside `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, where simplejson resides.

I thought it was an issue with my `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH`, but I've appended both and I still have the same issue.

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/python2.7:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: how about other packages that reside in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`? can you import them?

Comment: Good point. No. Except when I run python from inside /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: when outside of `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` try running python, type `import sys` and then `sys.path` and see the output. is there `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`?

Comment: No there's not. I tried appending sys.path and then simplejson imports just fine, however once I exit python it doesn't keep the appended path and so I still can't run my Odoo server. Shouldn't sys.path in python be equivalent to $PYTHONPATH in the shell?
Sys.path output: 
['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Comment: do you happen to have two python distributions installed on your machine?

Comment: Yes. My /usr/lib contains python2.7, python3 and python3.4. Figured that would be an issue. I don't need python3 and python3.4 at the moment at least.